# Running the crawler doesn't get the same data it does when training

Tags: import.io

When training my crawler to scrape a Yelp page, it gets all the information without me doing anything, but when I run the crawler, the address is not recognized, and doesn't record.

Comment: Have you emailed import.io support? It sounds like there is something different is happening on the server side when the import.io crawler goes to get the info, only they would know what that is.

Eg: yelp my require a cookie or something.

Comment: @CavemanDan no there is nothing wrong with import since i have done it before on yelp , he just needs to manually add xpath selectors .

Answer (score 8):

**Getting company data from Yelp**

In this case we want to get addresses for companies in San Francisco from the website www.yelp.com.

**Analysis of the site**

We can get a list of companies beginning with the letter “A” from this page:

```
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/1
```

This directory page tells us there are 42 pages of results for “A” with up to 80 results per page.

This is good news.

**Create an API**

I am now going to create an API to get the data from the first page and then use Bulk Extract to pass through a list of URLs to all 42 pages.

Using Magic, I can generate an API in just a few clicks:

1. Go to Magic.import.io
2. Paste in the URL to the Yelp page (link above)
3. Click “Extract Data”
4. Click “Get API”
5. Click “Copy this to My Data”

Now we have an API!

(Note that if you need more control over what to include or exclude from the API you can use an Extractor)

**Generate a list of URLs**

To generate a list of URLs that will allow us to get data from pages 1 through 42 I am going to use an external service hosted at:

http://texttool.blogspot.co.uk/

Locate the "generate list of numbers" tool and generate a list of URLs:

```
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/1
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/2
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/3
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/4
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/5
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/6
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/7
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/8
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/9
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/10
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/11
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/12
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/13
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/14
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/15
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/16
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/17
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/18
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/19
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/20
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/21
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/22
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/23
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/24
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/25
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/26
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/27
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/28
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/29
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/30
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/31
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/32
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/33
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/34
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/35
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/36
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/37
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/38
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/39
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/40
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/41
http://www.yelp.com/sm/san-francisco-ca-us/a/42
```

**Bulk Extract**

Now you can use Bulk Extract to get data from each of those URLs in one go.

To do this:

1. Go to the Configure tab on your Yelp API
2. Select Bulk Extract from the drop down
3. Paste in the list of 42 URLs
4. Click “Run Queries”

Note: you may get some failed queries. By clicking the “X URLs failed” text you can retry the failed queries.

**Export**

You can now export this data to a spreadsheet, as HTML or JSON.

**Further reading**

http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/669784-getting-company-data-from-yelp

Answer (score 1):

you should use xpath to select what ever you want on yelp , i have done it before for yelp and xpath is more accurate than manual training .

Answer (score 0):

I had more luck with http://datascramblr.com as does it all for you automatically for Yelp